# Unity 4 Spark when hitting wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I watched a youtube video how to make a sparks when like hit a wall or something but the code dident work

```
var particles_sparks : GameObject;

function OnCollisionEnter(collision : Collision)
{
    Instantiate(particles_sparks, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPdHwQAK9k0

does someone know how i shall make the code

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your question to describe what specifically didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my guess would be you didn't drag a particle spark `GameObject` onto the `particle_sparks` variable in the scene editor.

Otherwise, set a breakpoint and make sure `OnCollisionEnter()` is being called correctly.